# JavaScript: клик по перекрытому элементу

Tags: javascript, html, css

В данном эксперименте синий квадрат спозиционирован абсолютно, полностью закрывая собой красный. Допустим, по тем или иным причинам красный квадрат также спозиционировать абсолютно и добавить ему больший z-index не позволено. Можно ли при таком раскладе заставить реагировать на клик красный квадрат?

```js
var $redDiv = $('.div1');
var $blueDiv = $('.div2');
var $parent = $('.parent');

$redDiv.on('click', function(){
 console.log('OK');
});
```

```css
.div1, .div2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.div1{
  background: rgba( 255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.div2{
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) на том элементе, который должен быть «прозрачным» для кликов.

```js
var $redDiv = $('.redDiv');
var $blueDiv = $('.blueDiv');
var $parent = $('.parent');

$redDiv.on('click', function(){
 alert('Click on Red catched');
});
```

```css
.redDiv, .blueDiv{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.redDiv{
  background: red;

}
.blueDiv{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="redDiv"></div>
  <div class="blueDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!